# Apply css to all using * operator

Tags: css, wordpress

On a `wordpress` gallery each gallery album uses the following css to style them:

```
a.gallery-4050.gallery-link
```

So I applied some style content to it but it only works on one specific gallery `(i.e. 4050)`. Can I use the `*` operator in place of 4050 in the css code to apply it to all galleries? If not what other methods can I use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain if I understand you correctly.

You can't use a `a.gallery-*.gallery-link` construct. There are however CSS constructs that can help you achieve the required functionality

You could for instance use the ["attribute value starts with"-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) as follows:

```
a[class^="gallery-"].gallery-link { .... }
```

There are more of these selectors mentioned on [this page on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: This would fail for `<a class="custom-themed-foobar gallery-4050 gallery-link">`. I'd rathe use `a[class*="gallery-"].gallery-link` here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow!

In order to achieve what you're trying to ahieve, you should use the ["attribute value starts with" selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp):

`a[class^="gallery-"].gallery-link`

This selector will select every link (a tag) that has a class that starts with gallery- and the class "gallery-link".

EDIT: It will be better to use `a[class*="gallery-"].gallery-link` since it will also catch links that their first class isn't `gallery-*` (i.e. `<a class="custom-themed-foobar gallery-4050 gallery-link">`).

Thanks @connexo for pointing my attention to this.

Comment: This would fail for `<a class="custom-themed-foobar gallery-4050 gallery-link">`. I'd rathe use `a[class*="gallery-"].gallery-link` here. Also note there is no *class that starts with* selector - only an *attribute value starts with* selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is practically impossible to use the * on galleries alone. It selects All, all nodes (I know you know that). The lazy and easy way out is to give your galleries, the same Class name (some gallery plugin do not accept that so you have to inspect the html and get the gallery class name) and then add the style via the add css in customize.